# How to understand 【140 is almost 100 times less than 13000.】

Tags: inequality

How to understand these two sentences?

(1)【140 is almost 100 times less than 13000.】

(2)【7 is nearly 2 times greater than 3.】

---

In my opinion,
if the first sentences is correct: 140 (* nearly 100 times) < 13000 ,
by analogy, the second sentence should be 【7 is nearly 1/2 times greater than 3】: 7 (* almost 1/2) > 3.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because the word "greater" is the opposite of the word "less".

The number that is $2$ times less than $3$ is $3/2$.
The number that is $2$ times greater than $3$ is $6$, which is almost $7.$

The number that is $1/2$ times greater than $3$ is $3/2$ again, which is not near $7$ at all. So I would never say $7$ is about $1/2$ times greater than $3.$

By the way, sentence $(2)$ is badly worded because "nearly" implies that $7$ is not quite as large as $6,$ which is incorrect.
The sentence should say something like,
"$7$ is **more than** $2$ times greater than $3.$"

---

Actually, the wording of the sentences in the question seems altogether a little strange to me. The phrase "$100$ times smaller" is slightly better than "$100$ times less", and "smaller by a factor of nearly $100$" is better than either of those. In any case I think we are venturing into ordinary English rather than mathematical writing here.

Comment: Isn't the opposite of "greater" "at most"?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If it made sense to say "$6$ is $2$ times at most than $12$" then I might agree with that comment. In this context the words "greater than" do not mean "$>$".

Comment: There is also the issue of "greater than" versus "as great as". The former can be ambiguous as to whether you are talking about the increase of the factor. For example, 30 is 50% larger than 20, but 10 is 50% as large as 20. This ambiguity may be less when not using percentages, and "larger" vs "greater" may have different connotations, but can still cause misunderstandings.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis True, that is another reason not to like the way the sentences are worded. "As small as" does not work as well as "as great as" does, unfortunately, which is why I was considering "by a factor of $X$". Context might also help; that is, if previous comparisons were ratios rather then percentage increases or decreases, it would indicate that the more abbreviated wording also meant ratios rather than percentage change.